# Circular buffers

Tags: qgis

I have a coastal line layer ( `us-medium-shoreline` from http://shoreline.noaa.gov/data/datasheets/medres.html ), which is loaded into a project with On-The-Fly reprojection ( WGS 84 / World Mercator CRS with `+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`) and  I'd like to create a 500m buffer around this shoreline with the ultimate goal of intersecting the shoreline with inland polygons.

I'm expecting a polygon with the coastal line as its center, but I keep getting a circular region as resulting layer (with empty attributes table). Clearly I'm missing something as a GIS newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it is b/c your layer is in geographic coordinate system (Nad83) not projected coordinate system.  Perform a save as on the layer and change the CRS to a projected coordinate system then try the buffer on the new projected layer.

Comment: I've looked for a Projected Coordinate System suitable for the continental US, found one at http://gothos.info/tag/map-projection/ (`+proj=lcc +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs`,North America Lambert Conformal Conic), went to `Settings>Custom CRS` and created a new customer CRS, save the new projection, exited & reloaded QGIS, made sure OTF was on -just in case- and that both inland polygons & coast line were set to the new CRS, _but_ looking at "Set Layer CRS" for each layer I see: "This layer appears to have no projection spec"

Comment: It appears that CRS exists in Q already EPSG = 2163, +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: Don't use `Set CRS for Layer`, but `Save As ...` to another file name and target CRS.

Comment: @AndreJ: I looked at `Set CRS for Layer` on the new PCS _after_ running `Save As`, to confirm the new PCS was indeed using the CRS I expected (it did).

Comment: @artwork21 , I'm trying Q's built-in Projected Coordinate System.

Comment: Inland polygons & coast line & Project CRS are all set to EPSG:2163 (OTF still on). However, defining a coast line buffer leads to a "Feature Geometry Error". I'll look for a working example online, and work back from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what buffer size you entered.

If the source data is in degrees, the buffer size will be in degrees too, while a source in meters results in a buffer size in meters.

To avoid confusion, turn OTF **off** and see if both layers still align.

Comment: OTF is off, all layers are in the same CRS (saved as EPSG:2163, then reloaded in new project with EPSG:2163 as project CRS). The problem is that the layers are located in separate areas of the canvas (according to the coordinates, after panning each layer separately). Getting closer...

Comment: Can you add the extent of the layers, as reported by Rightclick, Properties, metadata tab? And the buffer size you have chosen?

Comment: This is more practical than select/panning each layer, thanks: `Coast:
xMin,yMin 2321544.64,258328.06 : xMax,yMax 2333464.74,277553.12` and `Cont_US
xMin,yMin -176.685,17.9108 : xMax,yMax -65.2246,71.3413`

Comment: Buffer size is 500m (I'm working off MA coastal lines until I figure out the appropriate intersect procedure).

Comment: The extent of Cont_US is definitely in degrees. If you have set the CRS of the layer to anything projected, it is definitely wrong. And Intersecting can not work.